# How do I keep a block of text on the same spread?

Tags: page-breaking

I am building a cookbook, and I need to keep each recipe's text on the same spread. I've wrapped each recipe in its own environment, so I can easily add commands at the beginning and end of each recipe.

I have a few questions; answering any of them will help a lot.

1. How do I keep a block of text on the same spread?
2. I've tried using the `samepage` environment, but it breaks the text to fill up a page. How do I tell LaTeX that it's OK to have a fair amount of space at the bottom of a page?
3. Is there a way I can figure out how much space a particular section of text takes up on a page? I.e. is there a command that prints it's location on the page in inches, centimeters, points, etc.?

Part of the problem is I'm not terribly familiar with the terminology. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `\newpage` to move it to the next page a solution for you?

Comment: By spread you mean two pages, correct? A left (verso) and a right (recto) page, or equivalently, an even (verso) and an odd (recto) page. Will your recipes always be 2 pages wide? Or some single page and others perhaps 2 pages. Give some examples of the expected output based on certain recipe lengths.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)!